# Quantum physics and hard determinism

Tags: quantum-mechanics, determinism, epistemology

Ok, I will try my best to ask my question without going too far into philosophy.
I am more or less aware of quantum physics and as far as I know it defies hard-determinism by saying that sub-atomic particles are completely random. Haven't all things in this universe a formula, but hard to determine by science and maths? Why is it called ''random'', just because our little minds can't know/understand it? Or is there something I am completely ignorant about this topic?

Comment: Nothing is completely random! You say"I am more or less aware of quantum physics " ever heard of the uncertainty law?

Comment: Trula, I am myself is hard-deterministic. I just wonder why it's wrong according to quantum physics. And yes, I heard the uncertainty law

Comment: Measurement outcomes according to standard qm are predicted by probabilities. How the probability "enters" from completely deterministic fundamental laws is open to debate, as seen in the numerous qm interpretations.

Comment: The math of QM (cos2theta) can be applied to two real particles that have been properly correlated as Einstein proposed. QM can be explained with a physical model instead of relying on probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to know a lot more about quantum mechanics.  To say that "...all things in this universe (have) a formula" would be an assertion of faith, rather than provable physics.

The only deterministic "formula" for quantum mechanics is embodied in the [Many Worlds Interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation).  In contrast, the [Copenhagen interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation) invokes randomness.